# vim no editor command. :SyntasticInfo

Tags: javascript, vim, vim-plugin, vundle

Trying to customise a JavaScript dev environment with [these instructions](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/29/equipping-vim-for-javascript/). I can build the Plugins with `vim +PluginInstall +qall`, I'm using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim), but I get a `Not an editor command: SyntasticInfo`from vim. I have the same problem with `:Helptags`.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE - some error logs

```
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] Helptags:                                                                       |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc                               |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc               |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-guides/doc                        |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-guides/doc        |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/delimitMate/doc                              |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/delimitMate/doc              |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/syntastic/doc                                |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/syntastic/doc                |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/doc                            |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/doc            |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/tern_for_vim/doc                             |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] > Error running :helptags /my/path/to/.vim/bundle/tern_for_vim/doc             |~                                                                                                     
[2015-05-11 16:08:50] Helptags: 6 plugins processed
```

UPDATE - my `vimrc`

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax'
Plugin 'eakuefner/goog-pystyle'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'marijnh/tern_for_vim'


set t_Co=256
set background=dark
syntax on
set textwidth=79  " lines longer than 79 columns will be broken
set shiftwidth=4  " operation >> indents 4 columns; << unindents 4 columns
set tabstop=4     " a hard TAB displays as 4 columns
set expandtab     " insert spaces when hitting TABs
set softtabstop=4 " insert/delete 4 spaces when hitting a TAB/BACKSPACE
set shiftround    " round indent to multiple of 'shiftwidth'
set autoindent
imap <C-c> <CR><Esc>0
```

Comment: And your vimrc contains?

Comment: Please describe what you actually did, rather than point us to some instructions you were supposed to follow.  Nobody has time to read that page and infer from it where you messed up.

Comment: ok I've added the `vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your vim plugins and autoload dirs - maybe you have installed syntastic years ago and forgot about it?

I got the same error as you and after I deleted syntastic entries in /autoload and /plugins dir (so only the only location for syntastic was in vundles bulde dir) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you,but i have resolve。

Please check the directory authority. Make sure user who run vim can modify this files or directory.